# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -- can't initialize org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple SpringMVC project (with Maven as project dependency) that hits a route and renders a view, and while I am able to hit the route (I am able to print a message from a System.out.print statement in my method) the view does not render and I get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException.

I printed out the classpath since NoClassDefFoundError can be related to that using this statement in my routing method:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
```

The only jars that appear are:

```
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/jsp-2.1.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/jetty-management-6.1.26.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
/C:/Users/cpfister/eclipse/luna-java-8u20/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1080/0/.cp/lib/bootstrap.jar
```

Based on this it seems like my maven dependencies (like spring-web) are not being placed in my classpath, so I am wondering if this is why I am getting a ClassDefNotFound error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, understanding the difference between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassDefNotFound would help. The first would happen when a file is not found at run time compared to the latter one which happens when a class is not found in compile time.

Your code is throwing an error("NestedServletException") and this exception definition is not found by your setup in run time. Please include "spring-web" maven dependency and make sure it is deployed in your server properly to fix this issue.

Once this is fixed, You would still need to fix the reason why this exception is getting thrown but hopefully you will get rid of this nasty "NoClassDefFoundError".